# aggregate and group three columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'],
                   'col2': ['action1', 'action2', 'action1', 'action3', 'action2', 'action1', 'action1', 'action2'],
                   'col3': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']})
```

it looks like

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   A       action1 X
1   A       action2 X
2   B       action1 X
3   B       action3 X
4   C       action2 X
5   C       action1 X
6   A       action1 Y
7   A       action2 Y
```

I would like to aggregate them into

```
    col1    col2            col3
0   A,C     action1,action2 X
1   B       action1,action3 X
2   A       action1,action2 Y
```

Order of items within the column does not matter. Basically i would like to aggregate col1 and col2. But differentiate the aggregation if col3 is different.

What is the approach I should take?

Comment: Can you double check the output? The grouping logic is unclear.

Comment: There's an error in his first df, it doesn't match the data at the top

Comment: thanks @Chris, but it's still unclear why B isn't grouped with A,C on X

Comment: @mozway it has as diff col2 list

Comment: @Chris, what is the error?

Comment: This, with your latest questions, looks a lot like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @QuangHoang i have envisioned the issues already. I am not new here. The challenge here is that if the problem is too complicated to begin with or there are many questions in one question, chances of it getting answer is very low. So I am breaking down the problems for the community. But thank everyone who bear with me and actually take the time to tackle the real technical problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably many ways to do this, but here's a solution that uses groupby twice.  Once to build the first set of actions, and next to group on the action and col3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'],
                   'col2': ['action1', 'action2', 'action1', 'action3', 'action2', 'action1', 'action1', 'action2'],
                   'col3': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']})

df = df.sort_values(by='col2')
df = df.groupby(['col3','col1'], as_index=False)['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df = df.groupby(['col3','col2'], as_index=False)['col1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output

```
  col1             col2 col3
0  A,C  action1,action2    X
1    B  action1,action3    X
2    A  action1,action2    Y
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to group on groups that have common values in col2.

For this you need to set up a helper group:

```
m = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(frozenset)

(df.groupby([df['col1'].map(m), 'col3'], as_index=False)
   .aggregate(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
)
```

output:

```
  col3 col1             col2
0    X  A,C  action1,action2
1    Y    A  action1,action2
2    X    B  action1,action3
```

Comment: Could you add some comments on why this may be better than the two groupby method in the other answer? The two groupby seems simpler to understand.

Comment: @drdot you did not fully explain the logic of your grouping/aggregation, so **you** tell me which one works the best in your use case ;)

Comment: both of the answers takes the same input and generate the same output. So I am not sure what you mean by logic not clear...Can you elaborate?